# How to downgrade OpenSSL on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, openssl

I'm using a version of the Amazon Linux AMI (v 2013.03) that comes with OpenSSL 1.0.1 installed as described here: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.03-release-notes/.

I have an application that may not be compatible with that version of OpenSSL, and I'd like to "downgrade" that to version to 0.9.8.  I can install that version with the following:

```
sudo yum install openssl098e
```

But I am unable to uninstall the 1.0.1 version.  When I try:

```
sudo yum erase openssl
```

I get a long list of what seems to be dependency processing and a result of:

`Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected`

Is there a way for me to remove the newer version of OpenSSL?

Comment: No, and you don't need to.

Comment: @Michael, could you elaborate?  Can I run 2 versions of openssl on the server? How can I be sure my application is using the correct version/libraries if I cannot remove the offending version?

Answer (score 0):

From [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=823346&tstart=0), which is about downgrading OpenSSL 1.0.2k to 1.0.1k, for compiling PHP to run in Lambda, you can pin the release version to an earlier version.  All you need to do is figure out what release version you need.

```
sed -i 's;^releasever.*;releasever=2017.03;;' /etc/yum.conf \
    && yum clean all \
    && yum -y downgrade openssl-1.0.1k
```